# Grouping and adding calculated columns to my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this I have made my continents my Index field. I want it to show up a little different. I would like to get the dataframe to just have 3 continents and then have all the countries that fall under that continent to show up as a count

```
Continent Country    

Oceania  Australia  53      154.3   203.6   209.9
Europe   Austria    28.2    49.3    59.7    59.9
Europe   Belgium    33.2    70.3    83.4    82.8
Europe   Denmark    18.6    26.0    38.9    36.1
Asia     Japan      382.9   835.5   1028.1  1049.0
```

So my output would look like such: and it would show just the number of countries under that continent. I would also like it for when it combines everything into num_countries that it gives the mean of everything for that country so its all rolled into one for each continent

```
Continent num_Countries       mean

Oceania       1               209.9
Europe        3               328.2
Asia          1               382.9
```

I have tried to create these columns but i can get the new columns to create and when I do they come up as Nan values and for the continents I cant get the groupby() function to work in the way I want it to because it doesnt roll all of the countries into just the continents it displays the full list of continents and countries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table for this. (I labeled the unlabeled columns with 1 to 4)

```
df.pivot_table(index="Continent", values=["Country", "1"],
               aggfunc=('count', 'mean'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following groups by 'Continent' and applies a function that counts the number of countries and finds the mean of means (I assumed this is what you wanted since you have 4 columns of numeric data for a number of countries per continent).

```
def f(group):
    return pd.DataFrame([{'num_Countries': group.Country.count(),
                          'mean': group.mean().mean()}])
grouped = df.groupby('Continent')
result = grouped.apply(f).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```